# is there a sandable compound I can use for a final skim coat over StructoLite plaster?

Tags: plaster

I had to rip out a 4' x 6' section of ceiling and wall to make a plumbing repair on our house. The original walls were 1940s era gypsum board reinforced at changes-of-plane with metal lath.

Some sagging of the joists had caused a slight bow in the ceiling, so I couldn't repair the ceiling with a piece of drywall, because the board see-sawed.  So I nailed metal lath to the joists and applied StructoLite like old-school plaster in three coats: a thick scratch coat, a brown coat, and a final veneer coat.

The wall turned out really nice with a creamy smooth finish but my overhead troweling skills aren't so good, and the ceiling has a lot of trowel marks.

So I want to trowel on a sandable skim coat compound which will adhere well to the StructoLite. What would be a good choice?

Any tips would be appreciated too.  Do I want to mist the plaster beforehand or wipe it down with a damp sponge?  It has been curing for about two weeks.

Comment: Should have used a float for the skim coat finish. Would smooth it out nicely.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a setting type of drywall compound like Durabond. You will need to apply at least two light coats to finish.

Comment: I would use a sheetrock topping mud it is lighter and very easy to sand. For finish work with topping mud I will use a 12-18” mud knife, it goes fast and ends up very flat.